# How to get context for createPackageContext call

Tags: java, android

I have a list of installed apps and I want to delete the caches of those that have checkboxes and I’ve seen code to do it but I don’t know how to get a context or to use this to call createPackageContext(packageName, etc.).  The method only compiles in a certain way but I wish I didn’t have this Catch 22.

My code doesn’t compile now

I realize I will need rooted permission as the manifest flag approach is deprecated.  So that is another problem.  Any help appreciated, maybe even reward you somehow.

When I tried to copy my (properly formatted) code to the edit box it doesn't satisfy the requirements.  I can't put my code into my post.  Can you please just accept one line?
Context c = createPackageContext(packageName, flags)

The idea is that I have a list of applications and their package names, and I want to get a Context object for each application.  The documentation for the method specifically says that you can get a Context every bit as good as if the application were running.  So I want to iterate through the contexts, and getCacheDir() for each application, understand?  Hopefully, I'm making it clearer.  Please, I have an enviromental problem using StackOverflow, my code doesn't post according to the rules, I've tried many times.

```
package com.example.delcacheapp

import java.io.File
import android.app.ActivityManager
import android.content.Context
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var listView: ListView
lateinit var tv: TextView
var arrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<*>? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    title = "DelCacheApp"
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView)
    var numapps = installedApps()
    tv = findViewById(R.id.readonlytext1)
    tv.setText(Integer.toString(numapps))
    }
    private fun installedApps(): Int {
    val list = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)
    for (i in list.indices) {
    val packageInfo = list[i]
    if (packageInfo != null) {
         val appName = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString()
         val appDir = packageInfo.applicationInfo.dataDir.toString()
         val packageName = packageInfo.packageName.toString()
         val launchintent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
         val appLabel = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
         packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0)).toString()
         Log.e("App List$i", appName)
         Log.e("TAG", appDir)
         Log.e("TAG", packageName)
         Log.e("TAG", launchintent.toString())
         Log.e("TAG", appLabel)
         Context testC = this
         //Context c = getContext().createPackageContext(packageName, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY)
    }
    Log.e("TAG", "Here are running apps ...")
    val am = getSystemService(android.content.Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
    val runningAppProcessInfo = am.runningAppProcesses
    var highesti: Int = 0
    for(i in runningAppProcessInfo.indices) {
        val processName = runningAppProcessInfo[i].processName
        if(!(processName == null))
        {
            Log.e("TAG", processName)
        }
        highesti++
    }
    Log.e("TAG", highesti.toString())

    arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this,
        R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list as List<*>)
    listView.adapter = arrayAdapter
    return list.size
}
}
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is how to get around the error "Classifier Context does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here" at the line where I make the createPackageContext call. I've tried substituting the this pointer, getContext(), getApplication(), but should I derive a class and put in a companion object block or something?  I just cannot get the code to compile unless I use a val or var keyword which isn't the right type.  And over the equals sign it says "Expecting an element".  Somehow I have to get an instance of a class or something to be able to use the method createPackageContext since I cannot just call it statically since kotlin doesn't have static methods.  Perhaps I need to use the Activity class which I have an instance of.  I need an object somehow I guess.  I'm just a little confused at how to get the code to compile - how can I initialize Context c if I don't have a companion object?

Hopefully, this helps everyone see that I'm getting a list of installed apps, then I'm trying to get the context for each app using the line that is commented out because it doesn't compile.  Enjoy!

I believe that I just have to change Context C to val c.  Maybe I am really asking why do I have to use val rather than Context?

So the solution I am ALREADY proposing is to just use val C = createPackageContext(packageName, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY).  I tried this on a Chatbot and I've now compiled and run the code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My apologies, I have been having browser problems, ..., here is a code snippet.  Note that I am struggling with just how to get a good context even though I know how it's defined in the class library.  Sorry I'm drawing a blank on why I can't just feed a packageName into the method and get the context for that particular app.  Here's the code that prints the list to the screen already working fine.  Context testC = this
                //Context c = getContext().createPackageContext(packageName, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY)  How can I get my code in here?